# Magento2 rewrite block not working

Tags: magento2, blocks

I want to rewrite the block: `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address`

Here is my code:
**di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address" type="Freedom\Adminorder\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address" />
</config>
```

**Address.php**

```
    <?php
namespace Freedom\Adminorder\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

class Address extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Address {
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
                                \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
                                \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreate,
                                PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
                                \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
                                \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor,
                                \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
                                \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
                                \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $customerFormFactory,
                                \Magento\Customer\Model\Options $options,
                                \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $addressHelper,
                                \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressService,
                                \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteriaBuilder,
                                \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
                                \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper,
                                array $data = []) {
        parent::__construct($context, $sessionQuote, $orderCreate, $priceCurrency, $formFactory, $dataObjectProcessor, $directoryHelper, $jsonEncoder, $customerFormFactory, $options, $addressHelper, $addressService, $criteriaBuilder, $filterBuilder, $addressMapper, $data);
    }

    public function getAddressCollection()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
//            $filter = $this->filterBuilder
//                ->setField('parent_id')
//                ->setValue($this->getCustomerId())
//                ->setConditionType('eq')
//                ->create();
            $filter = $this->filterBuilder
                ->setField('entity_id')
                ->setValue([1,5])
                ->setConditionType('in')
                ->create();
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$filter]);
            $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
            $result = $this->addressService->getList($searchCriteria);
            return $result->getItems();
        }
        return [];
    }
}
```

It is not working. Cananyone help me?

Comment: Suggestion: remove the constructor from your code as you don't inject extra dependencies

Comment: Does your extension show under "List of enabled extensions" when you run bin/magento module:status ? Also is it listed after Magento_Sales?

Answer (score 1):

same issue 
seems like magento 2 can't rewrite not obviously declared classes, like `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address`

but u can rewrite `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Billing\Address` and `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Address` instead

Comment: extending Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Billing\Address will cause error whiling using billing address same as shipping address .